# Android emulator can't be stopped after leaving it for some hours

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-studio-2.0

I've updated to Android Studio 2.0. I'm trying to debug on this target VD: google_apis_x86 (API level 19). At first: it can be closed at any time by pressing the X button in the top right corner of the emulator's floating menu, but it can't be closed by powering off the VD (it's stuck at the "Shutting down" screen). Some hours later: it can not even be closed by using the X button, also the whole Studio becomes impossible to close. So I have to use Windows Task Manager. Why?

Furthermore, [XHR starts to return status 0 in the WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36662565/webview-xhr-status-is-0-on-emulator-after-hours).